# Running JavaScript code locally on Tomcat throws access control error for Kafka REST Proxy

Tags: javascript, rest, apache-kafka, cors, confluent-platform

I am running a HTML application, which has JavaScript code for HTTP request. This JavaScript code further calls (POST API) Confluent Kafka server running locally on same Macbook.

This HTML app is running locally on Tomcat server.

> Failed to load http://localhost:8082/topics/topictest: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

When I run this HTML app which has JavaScript POST XMLHttpRequest, I am getting the above error in Browser console.

Could you please advise, what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, You might want to check your [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) settings in Kafka server. If you are still having issues after that, you might also want to check
the following resources.

1. [CORS XMLHttpRequests in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272611/make-cors-ajax-requests-using-xmlhttprequest)
2. [If you are using localhost in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin)